# integrate facial recognition (model trained in python) in advance java projects

Tags: python, java, artificial-intelligence

I want to develop a WEb-based voting system in java. The system has facial recognition and OTP verification. I have a a facial recognition code in python and the model is 85% accurate. How can I implement facial recognition in my web based voting system?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: A quick [online search](https://www.baeldung.com/java-working-with-python) could have answered your questions already.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the python function in your Java code via ProcessBuilder, but it's not recommended unless you are confident in the robust of your python code and you are sure it's easy to maintain in this way.

My advice is to build a python backend service (using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/), for example, it's a light-weighted framework for python web services) and call your python service via HTTP request in your Java code. By doing this, the two programs are decoupled and might be reused conveniently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).